# Reading the boot sector to a buffer

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to write a program to backup and write the MBR.

The following code should read the MBR and put it into the buffer (puffer).

The display_hexdump() function displays nearly the same contents before and after running disk_to_buffer() and its not the pattern of an MBR certainly. Its just the random memory patterns. I can't figure out how to correctly use the functions of the WinAPI to read the MBR, I already read Microsofts help pages for the functions used in disk_to_buffer. I get an error at ReadFile().

The devid parameter given to the disk_to_buffer function stores this text: "\\.\PhysicalDrive0" if I input 0.

```
/*

============================================================================
 Name        : MBR.c
 Author      : 
 Version     :
 Copyright   : Your copyright notice
 Description : MBR backup program
 ============================================================================
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int disk_to_buffer(char * id, char * puffer)
{

    DWORD dwRead;

    HANDLE hDisk = CreateFile(id, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0,         OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    if (hDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // Fehler, wenn ein anderes Programm     liest
    {
        CloseHandle(hDisk);
        printf("Fehler bei CreateFile()");
        return 1;
    }

    if (SetFilePointer(hDisk, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN) == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)     //Setzt den Zeiger für die Lese-Methode
    {
        printf("Fehler bei SetFilePointer()");
        return 1;

    }

    if (!ReadFile(hDisk, puffer, 512, &dwRead, 0))
    {
        printf("Fehler bei ReadFile()");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
int buffer_to_MBR()
{

}

int save()
{

}

int load()
{

}
*/

void prompt_enter()
{
    char enter = 0;
    while (enter != '\r' && enter != '\n') { enter = getchar(); }
}
void display_hexdump(char * puffer)
{
    printf("MBR     hexdump\n###############################\n###############################\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    {
        printf("%02X", puffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\nDump     Ende\n\n###############################\n###############################\n\n");
    }

void clear_stdin()
{
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int main(void) {
    while (1)
    {
        char devid[100], puffer[512], file_name[256], file_path[2048];
        int userinputid = 'c';
        int wahl = 0;
        strcpy(devid, "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive");
        printf("Hauptmenue\n###############################\n1. MBR     speichern\n2. MBR schreiben\n3. Programm beenden");
        if (scanf("%d", &wahl) == 0)
            clear_stdin();
        display_hexdump(puffer);
        switch (wahl)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("1. Modus\nIhre Laufwerke:");
                system("echo list disk | diskpart");
                do
                {
                    printf("Waehlen Sie ein Laufwerk aus [Eingabe der Datentraeger-ID]: ");
                scanf("%s", &userinputid);
                clear_stdin();
                } while (!isdigit(userinputid));
                strcat(devid, &userinputid);
                disk_to_buffer(devid, userinputid);

                display_hexdump(puffer);
                //printf(devid);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("2. Modus");
                system("echo list disk | diskpart");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Programm wird beendet [Enter]");
                clear_stdin();
                prompt_enter();
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Ungueltig");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: may be disk is UEFI not mbr

Comment: The program does not check for that (until now).

Comment: Do you have the right privilege to read it ? This answer can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647752/how-to-read-the-mbr-master-boot-record-in-c.

Comment: The code is a mess. Like, you never call `CloseHandle` when you should. The only time you do is when you *shouldn't* call it. And then there's so much unrelated code, non-English text and comments, and funny formatting. Can we get a [mcve] instead?

Comment: Your code doesn't check what error code is returned.  That's the first thing to fix.  Without that information, we can't help you.

Comment: error messages should be written to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error is generated by the system, then should also output (to stderr) the reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The easiest way to do that would be to replace a statement like: `printf("Fehler bei CreateFile()");` with: `perror( "Fehler bei CreateFile()" );`

Comment: regarding: `if (scanf("%d", &wahl) == 0)`,  the function: `scanf()` can, in this scenario return 0 or 1 or EOF.  The only return the code is really interested in is 1,  so the statement should be: `if (scanf("%d", &wahl) != 1)`  and if the call to `scanf()` fails, want to either loop, redisplaying the menu, or exit the program after displaying an error message

Comment: regarding: `printf("Programm wird beendet [Enter]");
                clear_stdin();
                prompt_enter();
                return 0;`, the function: `clear_stdin()` has already emptied the input stream `stdin` so the call to `prompt_enter()` will 'hang' on the first call to `getchar()`.   Suggest removing that call to `clear_stdin()`

Comment: in the function: clear_stdin(),  `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char` and the EOF is -1, which is an `int` suggest replacing: `char c;` with `int c;`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>` for the `strcpy()` and `strcat()` functions.  The posted code is missing the statement: `#include <ctype.h>` for the `isdigit()` function.

Comment: this line: `scanf("%s", &userinputid);` is expecting the second parameter to be a char array, but it is a integer: `int userinputid = 'c';`  Since the input is a single int, the line should be: `scanf( "%d", &userinputid );`  and should be checking for errors, as in: `if( 1 != scanf( '%d", &userinputid ) ) { perror( "scanf for user input id failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: in the function: disk_to_buffer(), 1) the second parameter is expected to be a pointer to a char array that is 512 bytes long, however, it is an integer, not a pointer to a char array.  perhaps you meant to pass a pointer to the array `puffer[512]` 2) the returned value (0,1) indicates if the read was successful, BUT the caller to that function is ignoring the returned value and continuing as if the read was successful.